# navbar Navigation Implantation using amplify studio

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I want to implement navigation in my react app using Amplify Studio.
I am adding onClick event and In action I am selecting go to url. after when I am clicking the element It refreshed the entire website. also I do not know how to navigate to particular component on click event.

I can use react router but, I can not modify component generated by AWS amplify because it overrides the changes after the amplify pull command.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onClick() handler for your Amplify element.

In the onClick function, you can then directly use the useNavigate hook from react router.
The name of the element you want to override is in the jsx file of your component. Looks something like `{...getOverrideProps(overrides, "Analyses")}`.

In my case, the following code seems to work:

```js
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const NavBarOverrides = {
        "Analyses": {
            onClick: () => navigate('/analyses')
        }
    }
    return (
       <NavBarIronWeb width={'100vw'} overrides={NavBarOverrides}/>
    );
```